# How to insert and retrieve a json stored in REDIS from python?

Tags: python, json, redis

I am tring to make this code workig with python.

This is the code used:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='192.168.22.108', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True) #Docker servers.

your_json = '["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
parsed = json.loads(your_json)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

r.append('sabado', (parsed))

print ("Recuperamos de REDIS: ")
recuperado = r.get('sabado')
print ("tipo de variable de recuperado: "+str(type(recuperado)))
parsed2 = json.loads(recuperado)
print(json.dumps(parsed2, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


I am obteining this error:

Recuperamos de REDIS: 
tipo de variable de recuperado: <type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pruebas_web.py", line 17, in <module>
    parsed2 = json.loads(recuperado)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Basicaly what I am tring to make is to store a Json in redis a get it back.

Answer (score 2):

You're appending the desizerialized form of the JSON to the key. Change as follows:

```
# r.append('sabado', (parsed))
r.set('sabado', your_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='0.0.0.0', port='6379')

jane = {'name': "Jane",'Age': 33,'Location': "Chawton"}

r.set('d2', json.dumps(jane))
```